# How to $inc MongoDB Document Field with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mongodb

I am trying to $inc a MongoDB field each time a "Like" button is clicked. Because there is no data that I need to pass to the server (but maybe there is?), I am not sure what value to put for the `data` key in my `.ajax` call.

The post route below shows what I am trying to do when the "Like" button is clicked:

```
app.post('/like', function(req,res){
    var query = req.session.mostRecentQuiz;
    db.collection('mycollection').update(
        query, { $inc: {"likes": 1 } }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    } );
});
```

On page JS:

```
$("#like").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/like",
        method: "POST",
        data: , //what would go here?
                //I just need to $inc each time "Like is clicked.
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success){
                console.log("success!")
            }else{
                console.log("failure.")
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`true` for like,  `false` for unlike

try something like this `data: {isLiked: true}`

Comment: Thank you! `true` works, but `false` gives me an error "selector must be valid Javascript object".

So, I created a new route "/unlike" which is the same as the "/like" route except it de-increments with -1, and the AJAX call for `$("#unlike")` has `data: true`

Comment: I also removed the `success:` key entirely from the AJAX calls, so not sure  if that caused `false` to error. Thank you again!

Comment: you can use  a parameter, based on `isLiked` `true` or `false`, increment or decrement likes